# Creating random order symbol levels in graduated renderer

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, random, order

When I add a layer and set to graduated in QGIS it automatically first render the symbology with the lowest values, then second lowest and so on. But I want it to be random.

I tried to look under properties, symbology, advanced and symbol levels, hence this was not selected. The layer is a Postgres layer, I don't know if it matter?

[image: Symbol level not selected]

How is the default order of rendering symbols in QGIS 3?

Comment: You can control the rendering order of the groups by setting a different value for each layer. Features are grouped in layers and all the features of one layer are rendered before any features of the next layer. If you want a random appearance, you would need group features into apparently random layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting to control rendering order of symbol (see picture below), if you check the "Control feature rendering order" then click the button on the right you will be able to choose an order field or insert an expression.

[image]

Using an expression like  `rand( min,max)` should display your symbol in random order

Answer (score 0):

Its on the main symbology panel. Have a look at the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Yea, and as I wrote it wasn't selected, but I want it to be random.. (Sorry for not being clear on it)